# Scrapy get data from mongodb in the spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created a `spider` which scrape the websites `products` from the listing page.
Is there any way in which i can connect to `mongodb` in my `spider`. Get the list of `urls` which are stored and scrape those url's

Thanks..

Comment: you can import from the db and use that urls in spider.

Answer (score 3):

You can `import` the `urls` from `mongodb` in the `spider` itself.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient()
import scrapy

class Myspider(scrapy.Spider):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = MongoClient() #you can add db-url and port as parameter to MongoClient(), localhost by default
        self.urls = self.db.db_name.collection.find() #use appropriate finding criteria here according to the structure of data resides in that collection

    def parse(self, response):
        # other codes
        for url in self.urls: # self.urls refers to the url's fetched from db
            #do operations with the urls
```